# Display a tableviewcell before it has data

Tags: core-data, uitableview

Sorry for the tittle but i´m new and i´m trying to understand some things, as far as i understand, a tableview loads data wich is then distributed by the cells (dynamic) in a way/design that the developer wants and keeping in mind the model object.

I know this is a strange issue but i have been struggling with trying to do the inverse:

1 - the tableview loads cells with some textfields on them.

2 - the user fills the textfields.

3 - the user presses save, and everything is saved in core data.

4 - the tableview has editing mode, so the user as the possibility of inserting more cells, and the process repeats itself.

So what i want is kind of a form, the tableview loads the cells at first (so there is no data YET, and the user as to see something to fill :) ) and then the textfields are filled which will result in data. So in view did load, i will have an array initiating with nothing...i´m saying this because i see a lot of examples and they always start with some kind of data like A, B, C etc...or colors...and i understand it´s just an example but i don´t want to initiate with data.

My question is, is this possible? What am i missing?

Thank you, regards.

Comment: Have you done any research? Have you experimented? What have you tried? Anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not strange at all, and you can certainly do that. After all, isn't that what the Contacts app is? If you have no contacts, you can make one. What do you see? A bunch of empty field that you can fill in.

You can implement it without Core Data, or you can do it with Core Data.

And have you looked at Apple's basic Core Recipes example? Isn't that what it's about? It starts with no recipes. You add some.

> What am i missing?

I don't know. What is that you don't know? Do you understand how to customize a table's UITableViewCells? Do you understand what a UITextField is and how it works? Then make a table view whose cells contains UITextFields and use the text field delegate to learn what the user is doing.

By an incredible coincidence, I've got some code you can download, that does almost exactly what you describe ("PeopleLister"). It starts completely empty. Here's the interface after the user has added some groups and people:

[image]

See how the user can click the **+** button to make new blank person (two empty text fields) and can then fill in the first and last name. Isn't that what you're describing?

Here's the version without Core Data:

https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/tree/master/ch36p901peopleGroups

And here's the version with Core Data:

https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/tree/master/ch36p901peopleGroups2

Here's the section of my book where I introduce how to work with a text field in a table view cell:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch21.html#_editable_content_in_table_items

Here's the discussion of the PeopleLister example:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch36.html#_the_document_architecture

Comment: Hello Matt,first of all thank you for answering my post and being so helpful,i´m working on this issue for a long time(going crazy),and thanks to your image i can explain better what is my problem:You have a + button on the top left corner of the left image,if the user presses that he goes to the image of the right(another tableview).That´s not what i want.I want the user to see only the right image,he fills and when he exits to another tableview and comes back,the textfields still have the text.Now imagine that he presses + to add another row and fills,he exits,comes back and he has 2 rows

Comment: Well, obviously I didn't think I'd written exactly your app for you! I'm just showing you the *kind* of thing you will probably want to do.

Comment: and i really appreciate your help..honestly, i´m gonna work on the links you gave me...and also i´m starting to think that the "thing" that i want it´s difficult to perform, because everywhere that i search there´s always a + button to another tableview, so..it is suppose to, and i have to redefine my app.But i just want to be sure..again, thanks for helping me. Regards

Comment: But what you're saying is just not true. In the right side of the screen shot, when you click the + button, you don't go to another table view. It just adds a table cell with empty fields. Really.

Comment: And think about the Contacts app. When you add an address, you don't go to another table view. You just see some new empty fields to fill in.

Comment: Hello Matt, i´ve been studying the links you posted, and they are great, thanks again, but i´m having trouble when inserting a new cell (I had to change the code to my needs), I pressed the + button, and then the row only appears if i exit the tableview and come back again. Also i created a xib file with the cell and also putted it in the tableview, and the textfields appear in the wrong place.Could you help me?

Comment: When pressing the + button, you need first to update the model (so that it has the extra new blank data), then call `reloadData:` or similar to make the table show the new cell. It would be best if you tried to reduce the problem to something simple and posed it as a fresh question!

Comment: Hello matt, i have discovered the problem, now everything is working ok, i just want to thank you, you saved me from 2 weeks being stuck! thanks, really appreciate your help.

Comment: Hello matt,i was hopping you could help me,it´s related with this post.My main tableview has a + button in toolbar,when pressed,another tableview appears and you choose a "type" of custom cell to insert in the main.For this i have the tableview class,the popover tableview class and the costum cell class.I can save the number of cells inserted AND the text of textfields of ONE cell, but if i insert 2 costum cells at once,the text in the texfields of one of the cells is not saved. I can make a new post for this, but my question is,where should i be saving the text?i´m using viewwilldisappear.

Comment: Hello matt, sorry to bother you but could you PLEASE see my new post? i really could use your help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16157190/core-data-inserting-rows-and-saving-issue